# Registration Not Running Android Sip Error

Tags: android, call, sip, sip-server, opensips

Good day.
I am trying to open the sip profile which is pre-registered already.
The profile is fully working if i download any other SIP application from Google Play, but when i try to initialize inside my code, i get the error `registration not running` while opening the profile.

[Accordingly i was following this post for the answers, but seems the owner don't remember how he had fixed the issue -.-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682947/stuck-with-android-sip-for-voip-registration-not-running)

Anyway, here is the code of how i initialize and open the already registered SIP profile.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_SIP) != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.USE_SIP}, 0);
    }

    initSip();
}

private void initSip() {
    if (mSipManager == null) {
        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }
}

public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (mSipManager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (mSipProfile != null) {
            mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("faskjlfas", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}
```

And on click i open the local profile like this.

```
  @OnClick(R.id.login)
public void loginClciked() {
    closeLocalProfile();

    profile = null;
    try {
        profile = new SipProfile.Builder(usernameEd.getText().toString(), "sip2sip.info");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    profile.setPassword(passwordED.getText().toString());
    mSipProfile = profile.build();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

    try {
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, new SipRegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateStatus("Ready");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, final String errorMessage) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings." + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But as mentioned, the `onRegistrationFailed` callback is being triggered with the message `registration not running`. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You got any solution for this?